# Palpite repetido

Tags: c#, array, comparação, int, console-application

Olá, o meu problema é o seguinte. Eu estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em c# (console) para aprender c# e estou com um problema que não estou a conseguir resolver.

Em primeiro lugar realizo o sorteio dos números que irão ser sorteados:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] numeros = { rnd.Next(1, 49), rnd.Next(1, 49), rnd.Next(1, 49), rnd.Next(1, 49), rnd.Next(1, 49), rnd.Next(1, 49) };
```

De seguida mostro os números e ordeno-os (mostro na consola somente para eu fazer testes):

```
Array.Sort(numeros);
        Console.WriteLine("Números sorteados: ");
        foreach (int i in numeros) Console.Write(i + " ");
```

Agora pergunto pelo palpite e crio um array para receber os mesmos:

```
Console.WriteLine("Insere o teu palpite de 6 números: ");
        int[] palpites = { int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) };
```

O seguinte código é onde vejo quantas combinações são feitas comparando os números dos arrays:

```
int combinacao = 0;
        if (palpites[0] == numeros[0] || palpites[0] == numeros[1] || palpites[0] == numeros[2] || palpites[0]== numeros[0] || palpites[0] == numeros[4] || palpites[0] == numeros[5])
        {
            combinacao = combinacao + 1;
        }
        if(palpites[1] == numeros[0] || palpites[1] == numeros[1] || palpites[1] == numeros[2] || palpites[1] == numeros[3] || palpites[1] == numeros[4] || palpites[1] == numeros[5])
        {
            combinacao = combinacao + 1;
        }
        if (palpites[2] == numeros[0] || palpites[2] == numeros[1] || palpites[2] == numeros[2] || palpites[2] == numeros[3] || palpites[2] == numeros[4] || palpites[2] == numeros[5])
        {
            combinacao = combinacao + 1;
        }
        if (palpites[3] == numeros[0] || palpites[3] == numeros[1] || palpites[3] == numeros[2] || palpites[3] == numeros[3] || palpites[3] == numeros[4] || palpites[3] == numeros[5])
        {
            combinacao = combinacao + 1;
        }
        if (palpites[4] == numeros[0] || palpites[4] == numeros[1] || palpites[4] == numeros[2] || palpites[4] == numeros[3] || palpites[4] == numeros[4] || palpites[4] == numeros[5])
        {
            combinacao = combinacao + 1;
        }
        if (palpites[5] == numeros[0] || palpites[5] == numeros[1] || palpites[5] == numeros[2] || palpites[5] == numeros[3] || palpites[5] == numeros[4] || palpites[5] == numeros[5])
        {
            combinacao = combinacao + 1;
        }
```

Por ultimo mas não menos importante revelo o resultado:

```
if(combinacao == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Não acertou nenhum número.");
        }
        else if(combinacao == 1)
        {
            Console.Write("Acertou um número.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Acertou " + combinacao + " números.");
        }
```

Agora é que vem o meu problema!

Se eu repetir o meu palpite diversas vezes e esse mesmo número for sorteado somente uma vez ele irá contar sempre as vezes que eu der o meu palpite.

[image: console]

Provavelmente é algo bastante simples mas como sou muito iniciante ainda não consigo perceber, obrigado a todos pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

O jeito mais fácil é você verificar a cada entrada, em um loop, e só adicionar para a lista após verificar que o número não é repetido:

```
Console.WriteLine("Insere o teu palpite de 6 números: ");

List<int> palpites = new List<int>();

while(palpites.Length < 6)
{
    int palpite = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if(palpites.Contains(palpite))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"O número {palpite} já foi utilizado") ;
    } 
    else
    {
        palpites.Add(palpite);
    } 
}
```